# How to fix part of a variable of type array of set var in a data file for a Minizinc model?

Tags: minizinc

I have a Minizinc model and I have a data file. I would like to feed part of a solution to my model, but it keeps giving my an error.

Here is a simplified version of my model.

```
enum pieces;
enum beams;
array[beams] of var set of pieces: b2p;
(constraints)
```

Here is the data file :

```
pieces={p1, p2, p3, p4, p5};
beams={b0, b1, b2};
```

I would like to fix part of b2p variable like so :

```
b2p[b0] = {p1};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following assignment to b2p array

b2p = [{p1}, _, _];

that is assign {p1} to the first element of the vector and leave the rest unfixed.